# How do I merge two tables with dates within the key (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, date, merge

I've been wandering a lot before I could find a solution to my issue and I wanted to ask the community if you had a better idea than the one I came up with.

My problem is the following:

I have two tables (one table is my source data and the other is the mapping) that i want to merge through a certain key.
In my source data, I have two dates: `Date_1` and `Date_2`
In my mapping, I have four dates: `Date_1_begin, Date_1_end, Date_2_begin, Date_2_end`
The problem is: those dates are part of my key.

For example:

```
df
   A  B      date
0  1  A  20210310
1  1  A  20190101
2  3  C  19981231
```

```
mapping
   A  B date_begin  date_end code
0  1  A   19600101  20201231    1
1  1  A   20210101  20991231    2
2  3  C   19600101  20991231    3
```

The idea is that: doing something like this:
`pd.merge(df, mapping, on = ['A','B'])`

would give me two codes for key 1_A : `1` and `2`. But I want a 1-1 relation.

In order to assign the right code considering the dates, I did something like this using `piecewise`
from `numpy` library:

```
df_date= df['date'].values
conds = [(df_date >= start_date)&(df_date<= end_date)] for start_date, end_date in zip(mapping.date_begin.values, mapping.date_end.values)]
result = np.piecewise(np.zeros(len(df)), conds, mapping['code'].values)
df['code']  = result
```

And it works fine... But I figured it must exist somewhere something easier and classier maybe...

Many thanks in advance!
Clem

Comment: Is `date_begin` equal to `1960101` intentionally?

Comment: sorry it should be 19600101... Well done

Answer (score 0):

You need to add enumeration to the duplicate rows:

```
(df1.assign(enum=df1.groupby(['A','B'].cumcount())
    .merge(df2.assign(enum=df2.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()),
           on=['A','B','enum'])
)
```

Comment: wow many thanks for that. That's very elegant :))

Comment: Problem is, as it is, it doesn't include the information behind the date. The first line of df1 should be assigned to Code 2. As it is, if I merge df1 and df2 it won't be the case. But I love your method and will try to start from there ;) Many thanks again

Comment: It should work with a proper ```sort_values()```method though :))